# Angular observable subscribe call same method on next() and error()

Tags: angular, observable

I have a function that returns observable and I need to redirect to the homepage whether this observable returns data or error. Something like that:

```
  private initializeCurrentUser() {
    this.userService
      .initializeCurrentUser()
      .subscribe(
        () => this.router.navigate(['']), //next
        () => this.router.navigate([''])  //error
      );
  }
```

Is there any way to generalize next() and error() calls to prevent code duplication?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `catchError` operator. The operator handles errors in an observable sequence and returns observable so in subscribe you get only next value.

[RxJS - catchError](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError)

For example:

```
private initializeCurrentUser() {
 this.userService
  .initializeCurrentUser()
  .pipe(catchError(() => of()))
  .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `finalize` operator:

```
private initializeCurrentUser() {
 this.userService
  .initializeCurrentUser()
  .pipe(finalize(() => this.router.navigate([''])))
  .subscribe(() => {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no, you can not generalize `next` and `error` as `subscribe` is expecting callbacks for each. There are a few options, but I think they are more code and less clear. Let's look at one and see why.

`Observable.subscribe` can be called two different ways. One is by passing the callbacks for `next`, `error`, and `complete` like you did above. Another is by passing it an `Observer` object. This `Observer` object will let you do something like what you are asking for.

Let's create an `Observer` that has a method for `next` that handles your redirect, and a method for `error` that just calls `next`.

```js
const redirectObserver = {
  next() {
    this.router.navigate([''])
  },
  error() {
    this.next()
  }
};
```

Now we can use that in your original example by passing this to `Observable.subscribe()`

```js
private initializeCurrentUser() {
  this.userService
    .initializeCurrentUser()
    .subscribe(redirectObserver);
}
```

This will work! When the `Observable` emits or errors, the call to the router's navigate method will fire. My argument against this is that commonly `next` and `error` are different, and this approach hides that we are breaking convention. Even if we really want to handle them the same way, we can be very explicit about it.

What about just pulling out the duplicate logic to a helper method? This has the same result as what you want to do, and allows the code and intention to be clear.

```js
private redirectToHomepage() {
  this.router.navigate(['']);
}

private initializeCurrentUser() {
  this.userService
    .initializeCurrentUser()
    .subscribe(
      () => this.redirectToHomepage(), //next
      () => this.redirectToHomepage()  //error
    );
}
```

Now if you want to change where the redirect goes to or add additional logic it will only be in one place, the definition of `redirectToHomepage`, instead of in both `next` and `error`. Our previous example had this benefit as well, but now we are being very explicit and it is easy to see that we expect the same behavior when `next` or `error` is fired.

RXJS Observable examples here: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Observable